# giving a name to a composite type in Rascal (a la typedef)

Tags: typedef, rascal

In Rascal, how do I introduce a name for a composite type (that's constructed from built-in basic types and type constructors like list and map)?
E.g. I'd like to do something like

```
typedef IntList = list[int];
typedef StrToIntList = map[str,IntList];
StrToIntList mymap = ();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `typedef` you can use `alias`. For instance:

```
rascal>alias IntList = list[int];
ok
rascal>alias StrToIntList = map[str,IntList];
ok
rascal>StrToIntList mymap = ();
StrToIntList: ()
```

You can use `alias` to give alternate names to existing basic types as well, so you could also do something like:

```
alias ID = int;
```

And, you can include type parameters if needed, so a graph over an arbitrary type could be defined as:

```
alias Graph[&T] = rel[&T,&T];
```

Note that an `alias` introduces a type equivalence and not just a sub-type. So for any function that accepts the alias as argument type, you can also provide a value of the type that it aliases, or any of its sub-types.